# How to use gson to convert json which contains java's keyword?

Tags: java, gson

I'm using `new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, javabean.class)` to convert json into java bean;

But there is some key named `abstract` in json String ,like this:

```
{
    abstract : "value"
}
```

If I want to write java bean , it should like this:

```
public class JavaBean
{
    private String abstract;
}
```

And use `new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JavaBean.class)` to parse the data into class JavaBean. But in Java , the `abstract` is key word ,I can't write class like this, it will report error when I compiling my code. So I'm looking up some way to get my code through.

Comment: @HotLicks I have used JSON for more than one year. You can see my update to get what is my real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to name the field in your bean differently and annotate it with `@SerializedName("abstract")`.

E.g.

```
public class JavaBean
{
    @SerializedName("abstract")
    private String abst;
}
```

Comment: How can I write into my java code since the abstract is key word?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: have updated my question.

Comment: @zzy Have updated my answer